# how to resolve splash screen issue for windows phone 8

Tags: splash-screen, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

My splash screen stays for 4 seconds when the app launches and for the first second it's perfect but for the other 3 seconds it's getting bulged a little bit downwards, in windows phone 8.1 application build using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0.

for the code link [1]: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwLUeOHO6JdPdGxfS3RsY3d4NU0

Comment: You did not provide any code to debug. Provide code.

Comment: i just paste the spalsh screen in the windows environment that it i am not write any code for that

Comment: Zip and upload the native folder of your Windows Phone environment from MobileFirst Studio.

Comment: how to upload the zip file in this question

Comment: Just use Dropbox or Google Drive??

Comment: i added please check it

Comment: When using custom splash screens, ensure you meet the Microsoft stipulated resolutions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769511(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Appsplashscreens

Comment: in mobile first platform there given resolutions i followed that only

Comment: @KranthiVenkataChikkadamalla, the file is not available - remove the quest for permission so we could download it!

Comment: i don't know how to remove the quest i can share you can you send the gmail id

Comment: I have already sent a request for authorization. Check your email.......

Comment: yes i share to you  please check it

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 8 Silverlight this is expected because  the top tray of the OS is displayed as the splash screen is showing and the application is loading. Initially this tray is hidden by the OS and then comes to view.